# Проблема с запуском PostgreSQL на Arch Linux через systemctl. Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: postgresql, archlinux

Решил я значит поставить PostgreSQL на Arch Linux. Решил воспользоваться [данным мануалом](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-configure-and-upgrade-postgresql-on-arch-linux/).

1. Обновил пакеты командой `sudo pacman -Syyu`
2. Установил postgresql командой `sudo pacman -S postgresql`

Тут пока всё нормально. Следующим этапом автор мануала предлагает мне ввести команду `sudo -u postgres –i  initdb -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'`. И мне выдало ошибку:

```
sudo: –i: command not found
```

Данная проблема не давала мне возможность успешно запустить postgresql.service командой `sudo systemctl start postgresql.service` и кидала ошибку

```
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql.service" for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить данную проблему, мне предложили ввести команду `systemctl status postgresql.service` ввывод которой показан ниже

```
× postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-07-21 13:20:02 MSK; 20s ago
    Process: 3945 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 41ms

Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome postgres[3945]: "/var/lib/postgres/data" is missing or empty. Use a command like
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome postgres[3945]:   su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome postgres[3945]: with relevant options, to initialize the database cluster.
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 21 13:20:02 noxethome systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

И я воспользовался командой `su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"` которую можно найти на 9 строке вывода от `systemctl status postgresql.service`

После этого запуск `postgresql.service` не составил труда.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo -u postgres –i  initdb

Обратите внимание, что символ `-` и символ `–` - это разные символы. А должен быть один и тот же `-`. Осторожнее при копировании. Юникод нам дал множество новых символов, выглядящих похожими, но разных с точки зрения машины.